# How to replace missing images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onerror

I want to replace missing images
Tried this code inside and outsite of document.ready function
Also tried to place it inside head of page - without success
Simply - missing images are not replaced

```
$('.item').on('error', function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'ph/vposter.jpg');
});
```

Comment: that event might have already fired

Comment: @DanielA.White - Should not be if the code is inside head tag

Comment: but then at that time the Dom elements haven't loaded and can't be bound to. you might want to read up on delegated events